# Windows fd_set structure

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets

I have a working code In Linux, which am porting to Windows. It using socket library.

When I declare `fd_set xyz`  , it through an error saying that `error C2065: 'xyz' : undeclared identifier.`

I think the same code should work in both the OS without any modifications.

Can anyone give me some suggestions.

Comment: I suspect that windows don't know about `select`. You might perhaps prefer to use some event library ported to Windows. Both QtCore (from Qt) and Glib (from GTK) have one (and you could find some others).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the Linux header `sys/select.h`, you need to include the header `Winsock2.h`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)